# Pythonic way to iterate over sequence, 4 items at a time

Tags: python, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

I am reading in some PNG data, which has 4 channels per pixel.  I would like to iterate over the data 1 pixel at a time (meaning every 4 elements = 1 pixel, rgba).

```
red_channel = 0
while red_channel < len(raw_png_data):
    green_channel, blue_channel, alpha_channel = red_channel +1, red_channel +2, red_channel +3
    # do something with my 4 channels of pixel data ... raw_png_data[red_channel] etc
    red_channel += 4
```

This way doesnt really seem "right".  Is there a more Pythonic way to iterate over a sequence, 4 items at a time, and have those 4 items unpacked?

Answer (score 42):

(Python's itertools should really make [all recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) as standard functions...)

You could use the `grouper` function:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Then you can iterate the pixels by

```
for r,g,b,a in grouper(4, raw_png_data):
  ....
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
irpd = iter(raw_png_data)
for r,g,b,a in zip(irpd, irpd, irpd, irpd):  # use itertools.izip in Python 2.x
  ....
```

Note that this will chop the last few bytes if the iterable's length is not a multiple of 4. OTOH, the `grouper` function uses `izip_longest`, so the extra bytes will be padded with None for that.

Answer (score 36):

```
vars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for a, b, c, d in zip(*[iter(vars)]*4):
    print a, b, c, d
```

Comment: But note. This solutions will works only for vars list length aliquot to 4, for iterating by 4

Comment: This works for me, but as @EugeneNagorny is saying, anyone using this should note that if your list has fewer items than a multiple of the "aliquot", it will omit the "remainder". For example, for ten values in a list and an aliquot of 4, it will only emit two sets of four values, ignoring the last two.

Answer (score 9):

```
from itertools import izip
for r,g,b,a in izip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for r, g, b, t in (data[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0, len(data)/4*4, 4)):
    print r, g, b, t
```

Comment: Not all sequences support indexing. `data` could very well be a generator.

Answer (score -4):

Try something like this:

```
for red, green, blue, alpha in raw_png_data:
    #do something
```

You can pull out multiple items and never have to use an iterator. :)

Edit: This would mean that raw_png_data needs to be a list of 4 value tuples. It would be most pythonic to put each rgba group into a tuple and then append it to raw_png_data and iterate through like my example.

Comment: Obviously this will not work, unless raw_png_data is a list of tuples. Right?

Comment: Yeah, but it would be a good idea when raw_png_data is created, to group them into tuples since each group of 4 values is related.

Comment: @excid3 That's what this question is asking for, how to group the raw sequence into tuples.