# How to transform a complicated list to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such a list

```html
[9308, '127.05', [{'id': 8568, 'name': 'some product name', 'product_id': 4204, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '139.00', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '118.15', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [], 'sku': '', 'price': 118.15}], 9306, '98.89', [{'id': 8566, 'name': 'some product name', 'product_id': 4200, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '89.99', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '89.99', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [], 'sku': '', 'price': 89.99}]
```

I'd like to transform it into a data frame that looks like:

```
ID   Total Value     Product IDs
9308   127.05        4204
9306   98.89         4200
etc.
```

also some IDs could have few product ids, so the list should look like:

```
ID   Total Value     Product IDs
9308   127.05        4204
9308   127.05        4200
9308   127.05        5555
```

Can anyone help me? I'm a very beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, and your input list is really structured well, then you can use some hard coding like this:

```
df_out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(l[::3], columns=['ID']), 
                    pd.DataFrame(l[1::3], columns=['Total Value']), 
                    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in l[2::3]], ignore_index=True)
                      .loc[:, 'product_id']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     ID Total Value  product_id
0  9308      127.05        4204
1  9306       98.89        4200
```

Comment: in your case it takes only first product_id for ID. As I said one ID can have multipple product ids

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `grouper` recipe from `itertools` to easily do this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```py
# Copied from itertools recipes link above
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then you use that to iterate through your data in chunks of 3, and combine it into a `defaultdict` to build your data into the correct format for a `DataFrame`

```
import collections

clean_data = collections.defaultdict(list)

for entry_id, total_value, product_json in grouper(data, 3):
    for record in product_json:
        clean_data["id"].append(entry_id)
        clean_data["total_value"].append(total_value)
        clean_data["product_id"].append(record["product_id"])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(clean_data)
print(df)
     id total_value  product_id
0  9308      127.05        4204
1  9306       98.89        4200
```

This will also handle the case where you have more than 1 record in the 3rd of your data (e.g. if you have 2 dictionaries in your list, instead of just 1)

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that the array has a structure of ID, Total Value and product info that is encoded as json. If we loop through that array three items at a time, then the below should work fine:

```
def unzip(i,v,d):
    return pd.DataFrame(d).assign(ID=i, TotalValue=v )
df = pd.concat([unzip(i,v,d) for i, v, d in zip(*[iter(js)]*3)])
df[['ID','TotalValue', 'product_id']]
```

Example output:

[image]

Notes: Details on how to [iterate multiple items at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415072/pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-sequence-4-items-at-a-time).
When working with json, I find it easier to create a dataframe first, and then add additional columns that are broadcasted to all dataframe rows.

Assumption: input string was missing closing "]" otherwise it is not an array. The above code works with this input.

```
js = [ 9308, '127.05', [{'id': 8568, 'name': 'some product name', 'product_id': 4204, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '139.00', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '118.15', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [], 'sku': '', 'price': 118.15}], 
        9306, '98.89',  [{'id': 8566, 'name': 'some product name', 'product_id': 4200, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 1, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '89.99', 'subtotal_tax': '0.00', 'total': '89.99', 'total_tax': '0.00', 'taxes': [], 'meta_data': [], 'sku': '', 'price': 89.99}]]
```

Comment: oh sorry,it doesn't work. It takes first id (like: [{'id': 8568) not product_id

Comment: It is replicating your expected result. Could you provide an example input where it is not working?