# text file to empty dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

```
dictionary = {}
file = 'lightning.txt'
with open(file) as d:
    for line in d:
        pa = line.split()
        dictionary[pa[0]] = pa[1:]

print(dictionary)
```

I have a text file that shows lightning players and their goals and assists, it is set up like this:

```
Stamkos
46
50
Hedman
30
50
Point
40
50
```

All on separate lines, I am trying to write a program that sends this text file to a dictionary although my output is not displaying how I want it. the dictionary is coming out as `{'Stamkos': [], '46': [], '50': [],` I am trying to get rid of the empty lists and just have the name as the key and the goals and assists as the values but nothing is working.

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415072/pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-sequence-4-items-at-a-time) help at all?

Comment: What result do you *want*, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the values are in different lines. Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch the other ones:

```
dictionary = {}
file = 'lightning.txt'
with open(file) as d:
    for line in d:
        dictionary[line.strip()] = [next(d).strip(), next(d).strip()]

print(dictionary)
```

**Output**

```
{'Stamkos': ['46', '50'], 'Hedman': ['30', '50'], 'Point': ['40', '50']}
```

Comment: this helps THANK YOU!

Comment: @Imbadatcoding I my answer help you, please consider accepting it. So it can signal others that your problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

you can use zip to read 3 lines at a time into 3 separate variables:

```
players = dict()
with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
    for name,goals,assists in zip(f,f,f):
        players[name.strip()] = [int(goals),int(assists)]

print(players)
{'Stamkos': [46, 50], 'Hedman': [30, 50], 'Point': [40, 50]}
```

Or in a dictionary comprehension:

```
with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
    players = {name.strip():[*map(int,stats)] for name,*stats in zip(f,f,f)}
```

Or a (cryptic) mapping of zips:

```
with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
    players = dict(zip(map(str.strip,f),zip(*[map(int,f)]*2)))
```

You could also structure your data as nested dictionaries:

```
players = dict()
with open("lightning.txt","r") as f:
    for name,goals,assists in zip(f,f,f):
        players[name.strip()] = {"goals":int(goals),"assists":int(assists)}

print(players)
{'Stamkos': {'goals': 46, 'assists': 50}, 
 'Hedman': {'goals': 30, 'assists': 50}, 
 'Point': {'goals': 40, 'assists': 50}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that also converts the numbers to ints:

```
file = 'lightning.txt'
with open(file) as d:
    names = map(str.strip, d)
    ints = map(int, d)
    dictionary = {name: [next(ints), next(ints)]
                  for name in names}
```

Result ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU1Na8MwDL3rV@jmGEIotBulsHuPhR5LD2Z2G7FGNrYgLWW/PZMztm63CgRPel/pJn3k5TrlaTrRJeAbmgude2HicydXMTCS9BhT4KYKWjSjsegK@g2gju/GTBIaY8xe3PARC6xe4WUB2@AHx7Bc1GMXiQVWFavQAjxV9reH3RCKOgaXmiK506XUorczq@k/pMLft6d3ocgu35S814gNHjhcpaqKbfGBj7Ph/5xinns1/rv/EyBllTePYAvT9AU)):

```
{'Stamkos': [46, 50], 'Hedman': [30, 50], 'Point': [40, 50]}
```