# Adding "sequential" information to python list using dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

### The problem

I would like to create a dictionary of dicts out of a flat list I have in order to add a "sequentiality" piece of information, but I am having some trouble finding a solution.

The list is something like

```
a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']
```

and I am shooting for a `dict` like:

```
dictionary = {
    'Step_1': {
        'Q=123', 
        'W=456', 
        'E=789'
    },
    'Step_2': {
        'Q=753', 
        'W=159', 
        'E=888'
    }
}
```

I would like to end up with a function with an arbitrary number of `Steps`, in order to apply it to my dataset. Suppose that in the dataset there are lists like `a` with 1 <= n <6 `Steps` each.

### My idea

Up to now, I came up with this:

```
nsteps = a.count("Q")
data = {}
for i in range(nsteps):
    stepi = {}
    for element in a:
            new = element.split("=")
            if new[0] not in stepi:
                stepi[new[0]] = new[1]
            else:
                pass
    data[f"Step_{i}"] = stepi
```

but it doesn't work as intended: both steps in the final dictionary contain the data of `Step_1`.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']

indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v[0:2] == 'Q=']

dictionary = {f'Step_{idx+1}': {k: v for k, v in (el.split('=') for el in a[s:e])} 
              for idx, (s, e) in enumerate(zip(indices, indices[1:] + [len(a)]))}

print(dictionary)
```

```
{'Step_1': {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', 'E': '789'}, 
'Step_2': {'Q': '753', 'W': '159', 'E': '888'}}
```

Details:

```
a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']

# Get indices where a step starts. 
# This could handle also steps with variable amount of elements and keys starting with 'Q' that are not exactly 'Q'.
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v[0:2] == 'Q=']

# Get the slices of the list starting at Q and ending before the next Q.
slices = list(zip(indices, indices[1:] + [len(a)]))
print(slices)
# [(0, 3), (3, 6)]

# Get step index and (start, end) pair for each slice.
idx_slices = list(enumerate(slices))
print(idx_slices)
# [(0, (0, 3)), (1, (3, 6))]

# Split the strings in the list slices and use the result as key-value pair for a given start:end.
# Here an example for step 1:
step1 = idx_slices[0][1] # This is (0, 3).
dict_step1 = {k: v for k, v in (el.split('=') for el in a[step1[0]:step1[1]])}
print(dict_step1)
# {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', 'E': '789'}

# Do the same for each slice.
step_dicts = {f'Step_{idx+1}': {k: v for k, v in (el.split('=') for el in a[s:e])}
              for idx, (s, e) in idx_slices}
print(step_dicts)
# {'Step_1': {'Q': '123', 'W': '456', 'E': '789'}, 'Step_2': {'Q': '753', 'W': '159', 'E': '888'}}
```

Comment: This works great! Would you mind breaking the dictionary comprehension down a little in plain English?

Comment: @AntonioCarnevali I added some details, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. The way you were counting the number of "Q"s was wrong and some lines of code had a wrong indentation (for instance `data[f"Step_{i}"] = stepi`)

```py
a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']


def main():
    nsteps = len([s for s in a if "Q" in s])
    data = {}
    for i in range(nsteps):
        stepi = {}
        for element in a:
            new = element.split("=")
            if new[0] not in stepi:
                stepi[new[0]] = new[1]
            data[f"Step_{i}"] = stepi

    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = main()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question:

We can group the items in the list, in this case, a group of three elements, and loop through them three at a time.

With some help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415150/11195542):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']

def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args)

result = dict()

for i, d in enumerate(grouper(3, a), start=1):
    dict.update({f"Step_{i}": set(d)})

print(result)
```

```
{
    'Step_1': {'E=789', 'Q=123', 'W=456'}, 
    'Step_2': {'E=888', 'Q=753', 'W=159'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First group by items like this:

```
a = ['Q=123', 'W=456', 'E=789', 'Q=753', 'W=159', 'E=888']
o = groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

then create a dictionary like this:

```
d = {i: [j[1] for j in g] for i, g in o}
```

then iterate over them and make your result:

```
result = {f"step_{i+1}": [v[i] for v in r.items()] for i in range(len(max(r.values(), key=len)))}
```

the result will be:

```
Out[47]: {'step_1': ['E=789', 'Q=123', 'W=456'], 'step_2': ['E=888', 'Q=753', 'W=159']}
```